# Minimal sum of natural representatives of subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $U$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ generated by $(a_1, \ldots, a_d) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^d$. Are there any theorems concerning the minimum of the sum of the natural representatives of an element of $U$, i.e. the term

$$(*) \min_{(b_1, \ldots, b_d) \in U} \sum_{i=1, \ldots, d}\phi(b_i),$$

where $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_p \to  \{0, \ldots, p-1\}$ is the function which maps every residual class modulo $p$ to its natural representative in the set $\{0,\ldots, p-1\}$? Or are there at least any known conditions which the $a_i$-s have to fulfill such that the term $(*)$ is smaller than a given threshold?

Comment: I don't know what can be said in general. Do observe that the sum
$$S=\sum_{x\in U}\phi(x)$$
only depends on the number $\ell$ of non-zero components of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d)$. More precisely, $S=\ell p(p-1)/2$. A kind of a worst case is that of $d=p-1=\ell$,
$(a_1,\ldots,a_{p-1})=(1,2,3,\ldots,p-1)$, when $\phi(x)=p(p-1)/2$ for all non-zero $x\in U$.

Comment: If, instead of $\phi$, you use the function $\psi(x)=\min\{\phi(x),p-\phi(x)\}$. That is, measure the shortest "cyclic" distance to $p=0$, you get the *Lee metric* or *Lee distance*, sometimes used in coding theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right, I forgot the sum sign!

Comment: Ok. Anyway, my point was that the minimum cannot be larger than the average of all (non-zero) elements. And the example shows that there are cases when the minimum (as well as the maximum) is equal to that average!

Comment: Right. Unfortunately, I am more interested in any kind of condition with respect to the $a_i$-s such that the $(*)$ is smaller than a given threshold. So, e.g. if $d=2$ and $a_1 + a_2 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ for two nonzero elements $a_1, a_2$, then $(*)$ is obviously equal to p, because for every element $(a_1, \ldots, a_d)\in U$ the sum of the $\phi(a_i)$-s is exactly $p$. On the other hand, if $a_1 + 2*a_2 \equiv 0 \mod{p}$, then $(*)$ is $p/2+1$, because there is an element $(1,a_2\prime) \in U$, which implies that $a_2\prime = (p-1)/2$ (constituting the smallest element w.r.t. sum).

Comment: In dimension 2 you can extend this argument to the general form $la_1+ m*a_2 \equiv 0\mod{p}$ for some nonzero $l,m$, and come to explicit results for $(*)$. But in higher dimensions it seems much more difficult. The only thing - as it seems to me - you can say is that if $\sum_i l_i * a_i \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ holds for some nonzero $l_i$, then it follows that $\sum_i l_i * a_i\geq p$. W.l.o.g let  $l_1 = l_{max}$. Then $\sum_i a_i \geq (\sum_i l_i a_i)/l_1 \geq p/l_1$. So, you have the lower bound $p/l_{max}$ for $(*)$.

Comment: But is this lower bound close to the value (*) if the $l_i$ are minimal - in the sense that there is no other set of $m_i$ with $m_{max}<l_{max}$ such that $\sum_i m_i*a_i \equiv 0 \mod{p}$? I have no idea...